# .Net Core Web Api Alexa Skill Signature Validation Fails

Tags: c#, digital-signature, alexa-skills-kit

I have a .net core (netcoreapp1.1) web API. One of the endpoints is used for our Alexa skill. I was able to resolve all the issues Amazons QA process except for signature validation.

For those that aren't familiar here's Amazon's requirements:

4. Base64-decode the Signature header value on the request to obtain the encrypted signature.
5. Use the public key extracted from the signing certificate to decrypt the encrypted signature to produce the asserted hash value.
6. Generate a SHA-1 hash value from the full HTTPS request body to produce the derived hash value
7. Compare the asserted hash value and derived hash values to ensure that they match.

Reference (I was able to complete all steps above #4 successfully):
 https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/developing-an-alexa-skill-as-a-web-service?ref_=pe_679090_102923190#checking-the-signature-of-the-request

[Here's an example of how many are doing this validation in .net 4.5 / 4.6 not .net core.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jj5kG.png)

Notice the SHA1Managed() class doesn't exist in .net core crypto or at least I haven't been able to find the right nuget package to add.

Here's my translation. Hash validation is coming back false every time. I'm logging out the signature and full body to and reproduce/test locally but no dice.

```
request.Body.Position = 0;
var body = "";
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(request.Body))
{
              body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

}
_logger.LogDebug($"Body is {body}");
var sha1 = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create();
UnicodeEncoding encoding = new UnicodeEncoding();

var bodyHash = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body));
byte[] signature = Convert.FromBase64String(signatureString);

using (var rsa =  cert.GetRSAPublicKey())
{
    var isHashValid = rsa.VerifyHash(bodyHash,signature, HashAlgorithmName.SHA1,RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
    _logger.LogDebug($"Is Hash Valid Response: {isHashValid}");
    if (rsa == null || !isHashValid)
       return BadRequest();
}
```

Comment: I think I found the issue! I cleaned up my code before I posted it here. In doing so you will notice at one point I was using UnicodeEncoding encoding = new UnicodeEncoding(); .... Then I changed that to ->   var bodyHash = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body)); Changing from UnicodeEncoding to UTF8. Its verifying now in my staging environment. I will report back if my skill passed certification.

Comment: Difference -> UTF-8 is a character encoding - a way of converting from sequences of bytes to sequences of characters and vice versa. ... When “Unicode” is used as the name of a character encoding (e.g. as the .NET Encoding.Unicode property) it usually means UTF-16, which encodes most common characters as two bytes.